# If a morphism has a section then it is an effective epimorphism?

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

In [*Topologies et Faisceaux* by **Demazure**](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~patrick.polo/SGA3/Exp4-23mai11.pdf), during the second part of the proof of **Proposition 1.8**, one finds the statement that (background at the end) the morphism $U\times_ST\rightarrow U$ is an effective epimorphism, and the reason given is that *because it has a section over $U$*.

**My Question:**

> Why is the morphism $U\times_ST\rightarrow U$ an effective epimorphism if it has a section?

I know why it has a section; it arises from the two $S$-morphisms $U\rightarrow U$ and $U\rightarrow T$. But I don't know why this implies that it is an effective epimorphism. While it is easy to show that it is epimorphic by the existence of a section, **I found no clues as to how to show the effectivity.** I think this should come from some simple arguments, but cannot figure it out.

Thanks in advance for help or references.

---

**Some backgrounds:**

We are consider $U\overset{v}\rightarrow T\overset{u}{\rightarrow}S$ where $uv$ is a universal effective epimorphism and $u$ is *quarrable*, which means the fibre product with every other morphism $S'\rightarrow S$ exists. And we want to show that $u$ is a universal effective epimorphism.

And a morphism $u:U\rightarrow V$ is an effective epimorphism if the diagram $$V\leftarrow U\leftleftarrows U\times_VU$$ is exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $e : A \to E$ has a section $e' : E\to A$. Then $e$ is the coequalizer of $\operatorname{id}_A$ and $e' \circ e$:

We have $e\circ \operatorname{id}_A = e\circ e' \circ e$: Let $q : A\to Q$ be such that $q\circ \operatorname{id}_A = q\circ e' \circ e$. If there exists an $u : E \to Q$ such that $u\circ e = q$ then it is unique since $u = q\circ e'$. Defining $u:= q\circ e'$ shows existence.

This shows that $e$ is a regular epi. Finally observe that a regular epi with a kernel pair is also the coequalizer of its kernel pair meaning it is effective.

Comment: Thanks, it is clear now that it is a regular epimorphism. But I am still having trouble showing that a regular map with kernel pairs is the coequaliser of its kernel pair. I found the reference *Practical Foundations of Mathematics*, but the lemma 5.6.6 is quite incomprehensible to me, without knowing such terminologies as **Galois connections**, **double slices**, and **coslices**... Maybe you are kind enough to explain why this is true? Thanks in any case. :D

Comment: Handbook of Categorical Algebra 1 Prop. 2.5.7 . If you don't have the book I'll amend my answer some time later. Right now I'm kind of tired...

Comment: Thanks, I found then [the page](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/regular-and-effective-monomorphisms-and-epimorphisms/) on Annoying Precision, which proves the statement clearly. Thanks again; this saved my day. :)

Comment: Alright. It was my pleasure.